# how to show Image loader when some action is performed on a web page

Tags: image, jsp, hyperlink, struts2, html

I have a jsp page in which there are anchor tags, buttons. Some of the links load the calling page itself with some specific data and some call other pages. The problem is when I click on submit or any other button to navigate to another page, the other page doesn't get loaded for quite some time and the progress bar in the current page progresses and after some time the other page loads blank and then it populates the data.

Is there a way that as soon as I click a hyperlink or any button whether it is calling the same page or some other page, before loading the data, a blank page is to be displayed with an image loader and once the data is retrieved, the content is to be shown.

How do I switch to the other page immediately when some action is performed?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a JavaScript click handler to your links and buttons so that the body of the page is replaced (or covered) by some initially hidden div containing a loader icon.

Note that that the real problem is that your application is too slow. You should investigate why all your pages are so slow before trying to find a workaround. Users, even if you show them a loader icon, will quickly become annoyed by a slow application.

Comment: well... its not the fault of the application as it has to do some processing and it will take atleast 40 - 50 seconds. So I need to show the users that the processing is in place. Could you please elaborate more on this Javascript click handler. I have never used it before...thanks

Comment: It IS the fault of the applicatioon. You could just start the lengthy processing in a background thread and directly forward to a page telling the user that the lengthy process has started but is not complete yet. Adding a click handler consists in adding an onclick attribute of the link (or do it dynamically at the loading of the page). The function executed by the click handler could just change the "display" CSS attribute of some div from "none" to "block". With the appropriate CSS styling, the div would then look like a loading dialog.